# generate an xml file from multiple nodes

Tags: groovy, opentext

on content server, I'm running this content script (groovy):

```
List<CSNode> var1 = docman.getFolder(129335).getChildren()
log.error("start")
for(CSNode x : var1){
sendFile(admin.exportXml(x).content)
}
```

I would like it to create as many xml as there are folders in the folder with id = 129335, but it creates only one xml.
I would like to modify it to create a unique xml file, with inside the xml corresponding to the
various folders. I suspect that the sendFile statement executed on the server could only be one.

Comment: what is the question or issue?

Comment: the script creates only one xml in the first for loop, and not as many as the directories contained.

Comment: check your `sendFile` function. without providing context/details - you will not get an answer..